# Change input value referring to database table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-insert

Its kinda complicated but I try to explain it ..I have a table in database somewhere looks like this. this is partno table

```
 ... |   Part No     | Convert | ...
 ... |    00000      |  ABC    | ...
 ... |    00001      |  DEF    | ...
```

All the input value must be start with 00000 or 00001, For example = 0000012345, 000014321.

Then, based on these first 5 value(00000 and 00001), it will be convert into like the Convert column.

Example:

Input: 0000012345
Expected: ABC12345

Input: 000014321
Expected: DEF4321

Meaning that I must convert the input that I got based on the table above and I don't know how to do that. So, I cheated and make the query like this:

```
Insert into pencil (pencil_no,lastdate) 
values('ABC'|| SUBSTR('" + pen + "',1,2), sysdate)

//pen is the input value
```

and it works as I get my desired output. But unfortunately this is not the right way as the data in the table will be updated and change.

Can anyone guide me how to do this? 
Thanks in advance

UPDATE :
I follow the guide from below answer like this :

```
insert into pencil(pencil_no, lastdate)
select c.convert || substr('"+ pen + "', 22, 11), sysdate
from partnotable c
where c.PART_NO = substr('" + pen + "', 1, 15)
```

and I manage to insert it in my database.. Unfortunately, there's an error which is **An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.** which I believe that the input I enter is not duplicate from any data in the table. When I run the query **a rows have been inserted** and I can view it in my database, but when I run the program, the output does not display.

I try following this method http://www.lifeaftercoffee.com/2006/02/17/how-to-create-auto-increment-columns-in-oracle/ by adding increement but still failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your insert statement needs to include a lookup of your conversion table, which I will call CONVERT_TABLE in my illustration.

You need to reference the input value twice, once for the lookup and once for the inserted value. I am using SQL*Plus substitution variables here; you will need to adjust the syntax to fit however you're running your SQL. Also you need to use the correct concatenation operator, which in Oracle is `||` not `+`.

```
insert into pencil (pencil_no,lastdate) 
select c.convert || substr('&&input_value',6), sysdate
from convert_table c
where c.part_no =  substr('&&input_value',1, 5)
```

---

This is a poor data model. Having one column represent two things, in this case a PART_NO and a (?) Serial No, violates [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). The consequence is tricky SQL, often when selecting from the table and sometimes like here when inserting or updating. The correct model would define the table with separate columns for each component of the key and a compound primary or unique key. If you need a concatenated version of the PENCIL column you can use [a virtual column to present it in queries](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1).

Comment: @PAC thanks sir ! I follow your guide but encounter another error.. I'll update my questions..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to replace the first 5 digits (`Part No`) with value (`convert`) mentioned in the `partno_table` as following and you can add it in the insert statement:

Giving '0000012345' as input

> ```
> SQL> WITH partno_table (PART_NO, CONVERT_) AS
>   2  (SELECT '00000', 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   3  SELECT '00001', 'DEF' FROM DUAL)
>   4  SELECT
>   5      REGEXP_REPLACE('&&INPUT_VAUE', '^(' || PART_NO || ')',
>   6                     CONVERT_) AS CONVERTED_VALUE,
>   7      SYSDATE
>   8  FROM PARTNO_TABLE
>   9  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ( '&&INPUT_VAUE',
>  10                    '^('|| PART_NO || ')' );
> Enter value for input_vaue: 0000012345
> old   5:     REGEXP_REPLACE('&&INPUT_VAUE', '^(' || PART_NO || ')',
> new   5:     REGEXP_REPLACE('0000012345', '^(' || PART_NO || ')',
> old   9: WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ( '&&INPUT_VAUE',
> new   9: WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ( '0000012345',
>
> CONVERTED_VALUE SYSDATE
> --------------- --------------------
> ABC12345        22-NOV-19
> ```

Giving '000014321' as an input

> ```
> SQL> WITH partno_table (PART_NO, CONVERT_) AS
>   2  (SELECT '00000', 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   3  SELECT '00001', 'DEF' FROM DUAL)
>   4  SELECT
>   5      REGEXP_REPLACE('&&INPUT_VAUE', '^(' || PART_NO || ')',
>   6                     CONVERT_) AS CONVERTED_VALUE,
>   7      SYSDATE
>   8  FROM PARTNO_TABLE
>   9  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ( '&&INPUT_VAUE',
>  10                    '^('|| PART_NO || ')' );
> Enter value for input_vaue: 000014321
> old   5:     REGEXP_REPLACE('&&INPUT_VAUE', '^(' || PART_NO || ')',
> new   5:     REGEXP_REPLACE('000014321', '^(' || PART_NO || ')',
> old   9: WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ( '&&INPUT_VAUE',
> new   9: WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ( '000014321',
>
> CONVERTED_VALUE SYSDATE
> --------------- --------------------
> DEF4321         22-NOV-19
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!